# Swift 5 / iOS 14 / How to implement Game Center achievements

Tags: swift, game-center, ios14, achievements

I like to add Game Center achievements to my app.

For testing purposes I created one leaderboard list and two achievements in App Store Connect and enabled them in my app.

Then I authenticated the local player in Game Center and called the Dashboard.

What I see is that one leaderboard is available. Fine. However, 0 / 0 achievements.
No achievements available. I assume that I should see 0 / 2 achievements but I have no idea, why they do not show up.

I also tried to report an achievement with GKAchievement.report and it seems to report without error.

But when I try to load any achievement, I get an error that no achievement can be found.

Any ideas what I did wrong or forgot to do?

[Screenshot of the Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnleE.png)